# How to track Mongo DB query response time in Production Environment?

Tags: mongodb

We are uisng Mongdb for one of our Application that is running in production currently .

Sometimes we are experiencing slowness in the User Front End (ie the Data is loading slowly to the User who has loggged in )

We want to rule out the possible issues of the slowness .
My question is , is there any way we can know how much time the Mongo DB  query  is taken to respond ??

Thank you very much .

**Updated Part**

Thanks , this was a sample result taken from the Mongo db develoment box

```
{ "ts" : ISODate("2013-01-02T19:11:16.822Z"), "op" : "query", "ns" : "ravi.system.indexes", "query" : { "expireAfterSeconds" : { "$exists" : true } }, "ntoreturn" : 0, "ntoskip" : 0, "nscanned" : 1, "keyUpdates" : 0, "numYield" : 0, "lockStats" : { "timeLockedMicros" : { "r" : NumberLong(65), "w" : NumberLong(0) }, "timeAcquiringMicros" : { "r" : NumberLong(4), "w" : NumberLong(5) } }, "nreturned" : 0, "responseLength" : 20, "millis" : 0, "client" : "0.0.0.0", "user" : "" }

{ "ts" : ISODate("2013-01-02T19:10:16.822Z"), "op" : "query", "ns" : "ravi.system.indexes", "query" : { "expireAfterSeconds" : { "$exists" : true } }, "ntoreturn" : 0, "ntoskip" : 0, "nscanned" : 1, "keyUpdates" : 0, "numYield" : 0, "lockStats" : { "timeLockedMicros" : { "r" : NumberLong(66), "w" : NumberLong(0) }, "timeAcquiringMicros" : { "r" : NumberLong(4), "w" : NumberLong(4) } }, "nreturned" : 0, "responseLength" : 20, "millis" : 0, "client" : "0.0.0.0", "user" : "" }
```

**But from this how can i really  know what time is taken for each query ??**

Comment: The millis field is "The time in milliseconds for the server to perform the operation. This time does not include network time nor time to acquire the lock." See explanation of all fields here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-profiler/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use profiler， set `db.setProfilingLevel(2)` to enable it.
and `db.system.profile.find().sort({$natural:-1})` to view the records

Comment: Thanks could yu please read the updated part in my question above

Comment: millis is the elapsed time.